# aifc module Error: Python won't open file

Tags: python, readfile

I'm just getting started with python so please bear with me ;)

While following a basic tutorial I ran into a problem while opening a file, here's the traceback:

```
File "/home/nick/Dropbox/workspace/pytest/schlange.py", line 55, in <module>
        f=open("file.csv","r")   
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/aifc.py", line 922, in open
        return Aifc_read(f)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/aifc.py", line 335, in __init__
        self.initfp(f)   
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/aifc.py", line 288, in initfp
        raise Error, 'file does not start with FORM id' 
aifc.Error: file does not start with FORM id
```

Does that mean that 'aifc.py' in my python installation is broken or did I miss something important here?

Comment: It looks like it's working fine - it's just the contents of your file aren't what the `aifc` module is expecting - hence the `aifc` module is raising an exception telling you why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've decided to import `*` from `aifc`, and its `open()` has shadowed the built-in `open()`. This is why we don't import `*`. Import the module itself instead and use the reference to get to its names when required, e.g. `aifc.open()`.